# trying to switch input radio button checked for every 3 second in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello i am new to coding and stackoverflow. i am try to make a simple slider but it is not changing image.i am trying to switch between input radio button checked for every 3 second. i don't know what went wrong

```html
 <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
              
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
           
            <div class="slide first">
                <img src="ad_1.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_2.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_3.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>

            <div class="navigation-auto">
                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let count='1';
        count.toString();
        setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('radio'+count).checked = true;
            count++;
            if (count > 3) {
                count = '1';
            }
        },3000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does provide [implicit type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) on the string `count` and makes it a number when used like `count++`. Your example still works without explicitly changing that type. If you want to sync the images with each radio button, that will require a bit more code.

```js
let count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio'+count).checked = true;
    count++;
    if (count > 3) {
        count = 1;
    }
},3000);
```

```html
<div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
              
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
           
            <div class="slide first">
                <img src="ad_1.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_2.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_3.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>

            <div class="navigation-auto">
                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is where you declared, count as string [ '1' ] and checking conditions as it's a number. better declare it as a number, i.e

```
 let count = 1;
```

OR

```
 if ( parseInt(count) > 3 ) {
count = '1';
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
              
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
           
            <div class="slide first">
                <img src="ad_1.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_2.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="ad_3.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>

            <div class="navigation-auto">
                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let count='1';
        count.toString();
        setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('radio'+count).checked = true;
            count++;
            if ( parseInt(count) > 3) {
                count = '1';
            }
        },3000);
    </script>
```